# How to set custom $_SERVER variable for PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, .htaccess, ubuntu-12.04

I'm working on a PHP web app which ALSO has some command line tools. I need the command line tools to detect the environment so that they connect with the correct DB credentials etc. The web app does this easily by checking `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` but that doesn't work for a shell script.

I'd like to create my own `$_SERVER` variable that the shell script can check. Ex: `$_SERVER['MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT']`. How do I do this?

I found [this](https://coderwall.com/p/mvcqcg/set-environment-variables-in-apache-for-php) solution, but I don't see the same files in `/etc/apache2/`. I also found this, but they're using .htaccess and I'm not sure if I have `mod_env` and also my app uses it's own .htaccess file, so it would have to be edited every time I deploy.

I'm on a Dreamhost VPS, which runs Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: `$_SERVER` will be defined either way but environment variables are there because of Apache, when you use CL to execute your script, Apache won't be involved in the process, so there will be no environment variables!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible. A shell or cron session is neutral and has no information that could help a script determine an environment in the same way as Apache does. In the Apache case, the requesting user supplies the environment with the HTTP host header - how do you think this could work for cron or a shell session?

Comment: @Sven I was hoping the shell script could look at... something... which would differentiate the remote environment from my local. For example, the app locations differ, so I considered checking against $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], which seems to be available in the shell. But it felt really hacky... but maybe that's the best option?

Comment: Can you run them separately? each with its own CL parameter?

Comment: Like a flag in the command? '... -env dev'

Comment: @SDP  Yes, I mean something like that!

Comment: The environment is not the same as $_SERVER. "I'm not sure if I have mod_env" maybe you should find out. The whole post reads like the XY Problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `php_sapi_name()` function ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php ) to detect the server API in use?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help me know WHICH server I'm on. The challenge isn't distinguishing CLI vs Apache. It's distinguishing which server either are running on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line arguments to make different and use `$argv`  array to access them:

```
<?php
if (PHP_SAPI == "cli") {
    var_dump($argv);
}else{
    echo 'WebServer';
}
?>
```

And its output:

```
C:\Users\user>E:\xampp\php\php.exe  -f E:\Apache\test\s.php 1st 2nd
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "E:\Apache\test\s.php"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "1st"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "2nd"
}
```

Few things about [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php):

1. This is a super global array.
2. First item is script name (or full path if you passed full path).
3. There is another super global variable [$argc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) which holds the number of $argv elements.
4. [register_argc_argv](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv)  should be enabled otherwise `$argv` will be NULL.
5. This variable is not defined when you access the script from browser(only for CL).

Comment: Thanks but remember the challenge isn't distinguishing CLI vs Apache. It's distinguishing which server either are running on.

Comment: I know that, but you can execute your scripts separately. For example `php -f script.php  host_number1` or `php -f script.php  host_number2`

Comment: When you say server, you mean domain? right?

Answer (score 0):

As you lucky said, Apache allow this feature like writing `SetEnv` in vhost config - it really works!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

So in PHP you will have `$_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV']` with value `production`

Answer (score 0):

The proper variable to check environment variables is [`$ENV`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php). This works both in CLI and in scripts run by Apache.

```
$_ENV['HOSTNAME']
```

Or you set whatever environment variable you want in your system.